# Adding new xml tag using sed in shell script

Tags: xml, shell, sed

I'd like to search and add new xml tags using shell variables.

Using below command, `KVM_IF_LIST_FILE` will store all the interface names of a `KVM` instance [it will contain for ex: `eno1 eno2 eno3 eno4`].

```
virsh domiflist $kvm_name|awk {'print $3'}|awk 'NR>2' >> $KVM_IF_LIST_FILE
```

Now I need to search for `<source dev='eno0/1/2/3' mode='bridge'/>`, if it finds the above pattern, need to add new xml node 
(`<target dev=\'$kvm_name$cnt\'/>`) next to the above pattern. I've written the below shell script, which isn't working in this case.

```
cnt=0
for i in `cat $KVM_IF_LIST_FILE`
do
echo "Updating macvtap device names for $i"
sed -i.bak "/source dev='\'/a <target dev=\'$kvm_name$cnt\'/>" $XML_FILE
cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`
done
```

Please let me know how to modify the above script to do the above search and replacements.

Comment: Use an XML-aware tool to modify the XML documents.

Comment: if you search here for `[sed] xml` you'll find 1400+ answers. Did you loook at any of them? Good luck.

Comment: It's actually *easy* to do this with XML-aware tools, whereas doing it with non-XML-aware tools is effectively certain to have corner cases wherein your code will create a corrupted document.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following document:

```
<root>
  <prior/>
  <source dev='foo'/>
  <successor/>
</root>
```

...we can append a new `<target>` element following the matching `source` element like so:

```
kvm_name=hello
cnt=5
xmlstarlet ed \
  --var kvm "'$kvm_name$cnt'" \
  -a '//source' -t elem -n target -v "$kvm_name$cnt" \
  -i '//target' -t attr -n dev -v "$kvm_name$cnt" \
  -d '//target[.=$kvm]/text()' <foo.xml
```

...resulting in the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <prior/>
  <source dev="foo"/>
  <target dev="hello5"/>
  <successor/>
</root>
```

Comment: I think that could and should be shortened to something like `xmlstarlet ed -a //source -t elem -n target -i //target -t attr -n dev -v "hello5"`. There is no need to add text to the node only to delete it afterwards.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs, the point of adding the text is to correctly identify the specific node. The goal is not to add the attribute to **every** target, but only the specific target we added during the immediately prior operation. If there were other targets already existing (say, for `hello1` through `hello4`), we wouldn't want to edit them.

Comment: I see. But couldn't that be accomplished by a more specific xpath expression?

Comment: @MichaelVehrs, one that takes, say, only the very first `target` after a `source` would be workable, if we were certain we were using the correct edit primitive (`-a` vs `-i`) to insert in that position. I like the idiom here because it's explicit -- if you have something that's a natural identifier in the context of your data, might as well use it -- and it doesn't rely on ordering, but indeed, it's not the only possible choice.

Answer (score 0):

As you might not be aware of yet, but will soon discover, parsing XML, as well as HTML, with [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) leads to trouble eventually. e.g. it is possible to have the same tag repeated inside itself; it can't be parsed with regexp.

First learn some [XSL](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (good [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_intro.asp)) to transform the XML properly. A good opensource tool is for example [xsltproc](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xsltproc1.html).